# Avoiding test synchronization timeouts in Protractor when long polling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, long-polling

Angularjs recently introduced $interval, the counterpart to setInterval to help avoid cases where Protractor would think the page was still loading when it was actually polling.

However, this fix doesn't help with long poll scenarios, where the connection is held open for x milliseconds then closed by the server. Is there any workaround for this, so Protractor will execute the tests correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why doesn't it?

```
$interval(function () {
    MySrvc.pollServer();
}, 1000 * 60 * 3, 1);
```

If you're only interested in doing it once, then just say so in the [third argument, `count`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval). Your tests will then proceed as usual without resorting to the dreaded [`browser.ignoreSynchronization`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/973).

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I completely didn't see that.

Comment: I'm in the same situation, but this does not seem to work for me. My `pollServer()` fires a `$resource(...).get()` request that is not fulfilled until the server wants to send a notification. (I.e. _never_ in the test.)

Comment: (I have to admit that instead of 3 minutes I set the delay to 1 millisecond. But I really cannot delay this poll by 3 minutes in the production code.)